# How to show alert if user tries to save values, that are already present my table for my Oracle Apex Form based application

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a form in my Oracle APEX based application, I want to have validation on submit button, so that the combination of two specific entries, if they already are present in the SQL table/View, I want to show an alert, like "The entry for this combination of values of A and B already exists, please enter correct values."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those *two specific entries* are represented by two form items (e.g. `:P1_ONE` and `:P2_TWO`), then the validation procedure might be a function that returns error text, such as

```
declare
  l_cnt number;
  retval varchar2(200);
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from your_table t
    where t.column_one = :P1_ONE
      and t.column_two = :P1_TWO;

  if l_cnt > 0 then 
     retval := 'The entry for this combination already exists';
  end if;
end;
```

The query itself might need to be modified, depending on what exactly you meant by describing the problem; that's the way I understood it.

Comment: For queries like that, I would recommend 'count from dual where exists' https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/efficient-sql-statements

Comment: I used this method, it worked for me, Created a validation on my page with type as "PL/SQL Function Body (returning Boolean)", and used little modified version of the query, instead of setting the retval, I returned   FALSE if condition matches else TRUE. And then simple we can give any required Error message in "Error Message" Section.

Comment: OK, I'm glad if the idea helped.

Comment: Now there is a new issue, this validation works well while creating a new entry, but when I try to update the existing value, that time also the validations trigger and stops me from saving any update in the existing table entries. The form page is same for new entries and to update the old ones. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can set a *condition* which says *when* to run the validation. For example, you can set it to run **when button pressed** (and set it to, say, CREATE button, which means that it won't run when you press SAVE ("Apply Changes", which is *update*)). If it is supposed to run for multiple buttons, then use **request is contained in value** condition. Button's name is equal to its *request* name, so you'd name all buttons you want that validation to run for.

Answer (score 1):

Then you should have a unique constraint on the table, and let that validate incoming data.

Any violation of this constraint will have exception raised, which can be transformed within the [APEX error handling procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/AEAPI/Example-of-an-Error-Handling-Function.htm#AEAPI2216).

Comment: Thanks Scott for a prompt help, you are always there for all my APEX related queries. Really appreciate this.